# Accessing a parent component's ViewModel property from the child's ViewModel in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have two components:

```
<parent-component type="permanent">
    <div child-component></div>
</parent-component>
```

```js
class ParentComponentCustomElement {
    @bindable public type: string = "permanent";
}

class ChildComponentCustomAttribute {
    public attached() {
        // how to get the instance of ParentComponentCustomElement here?
    }
}
```

I need to access the `type` property of the parent to add some classes to the child-component conditionally.

I could probably traverse the parent tree through DOM and look for this specific component, but I don't think that's the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can just @inject the parent ViewModel into the child component like this:

```
import {inject, Parent} from 'aurelia-framework';

class ParentComponentCustomElement {
    public type: string = "permanent";
}

@inject(Parent.of(ParentComponentCustomElement))
class ChildComponentCustomAttribute {

    public constructor(private parent: ParentComponentCustomElement) {}

    public attached() {
        console.log(this.parent.type); // permanent
    }
}
```

Note that this is also convenient as it traverses the parent tree until it finds the component you're actually looking for, so the child can be wrapped in a completely different component and this will still work.

Comment: You can do this, but now you've tightly coupled the child to the parent. Just be aware of this.

Comment: I think this makes sense in my specific use case, where the child component cannot exist anywhere else than inside of the parent (separator of a menu component)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement the bind() method for the custom attribute? Try something like this:

```js
bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
  console.log(overrideContext.parentOverrideContext.bindingContext.somePropertyFromParentViewModel);
}
```

Source: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/3

Comment: This doesn't work for me. For some reason overrideContext.parentOverrideContext is null. I figured out how to do this, posted a separate answer.